# Format both date and time together in the same input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input field that allows the user to enter both the time and date. While the user types, I would like to format on keyup. Would you guys by chance have a solution for this? Here is my current code:

```
.on('keyup', '.type-date', function(e) {
    $(this).attr('maxlength', '10');
    var value = $(this).val();
    var key = e.keyCode;
    if (!(key >= 48 && key <= 57 && 8)) {
        $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, $(this).val().length));
    }
    if (key == 8) {

    } else if (value.length == 2 || value.length == 5) {
        $(this).val($(this).val() + '/');
    }
    $('.type-date').attr('value', value);
});
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @guest271314 Sorry it should be like this 07/31/2019 11:58 PM

Comment: Is there a reason `<input type="date">` and `<input type="time">` elements are not being used?

Comment: @guest271314 From a Java perspective that is how we can sort through type. I created a new type that passes in time and date for this reason. I'm just trying to format it to make it easy for the user.

Comment: From this users' perspective the "easiest" would be two `<input>` elements, of `type` `"date"` and `"time"`, that does not interfere with input as user types. Though that is just this users' perspective. Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate the current result?

Comment: This line probably doesn't do what you think; the ending `&& 8` will always return true: `if (!(key >= 48 && key <= 57 && 8))`

Comment: I would use separate fields to make it easier for the user, and easier for you to validate. You can combine them into one string at some point later when submitting the data to the server (or even later that that, within the server code) in order to store them in a combined data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option

1. Check validity of entered date

var error = ((typedate.slice(0,2) > 12) || (typedate.slice(2,4) > 31) || (typedate.slice(4,6) > 60) || (typedate.slice(6,8) > 24)) ? true : false

2. If date is valid , Split entered date in format- MMDDYYHHSS

var date = $(this).val().split('');

3. Add slashes ,colon , AM/PM to the splitted date using splice

```js
$('.type-date').on('keyup', function(e) {
  $(this).attr('maxlength', '10');  
  var typedate =  $(this).val();
  var error = ((typedate.slice(0,2) > 12) || (typedate.slice(2,4) > 31) || (typedate.slice(4,6) > 60) || (typedate.slice(6,8) > 24)) ? true : false
  if(!error && typedate.length === 10){
     var date = $(this).val().split('');
    date.splice(2, 0, "/");
    date.splice(5, 0, "/20");
    date.splice(8, 0, " ");
    date.splice(11, 0, ":");
    typedate.slice(6, 8) > 12
      ? date.splice(14, 0, " PM")
    : date.splice(14, 0, " AM");
    var time =
        typedate.slice(6, 8) > 12 ? typedate.slice(6, 8) - 12 : typedate.slice(6, 8);
    time = time < 10 ? "0" + time : time;
    date.splice(9, 2, ...time.toString().split(""));

  $('.result').text(date.join(''));
  }else{
    $('.result').text('Invalid Date');
  }   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="type-date">
Date: <span class="result"></span>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/GzLOKG?editors=1010

Input :
1222192311

Output:
12/11/2019 11:11 PM